# Missing icons in SharePoint 2010 search results

Tags: search, pdf

I recently installed the [Adobe iFilter for PDF](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4025) to allow my server to index pdf documents. I installed with the packaged intaller and then followed the [configuration instructions](http://www.adobe.com/special/acrobat/configuring_pdf_ifilter_for_ms_sharepoint_2007.pdf).  I replaced the "12" with "14" when dealing with the registry keys because I'm using SP 2010.  After performing this process and starting a full crawl of my site, the search indexing seems to work well and all content, including PDF content, is being successfully indexed.

The problem is that now the icons do not show up beside the search results.  When inspecting the html source of the search result page, I can see that there's no `src` attribute in the image tags for those icons:

```
<img align="absmiddle" src="" border="0" alt="Item icon" />
```

Microsoft has an appealing KB article ([SharePoint 2010: Document Icons are not displayed in search results](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2646696)), which sounds like exactly what I need, but following its instructions to make sure there's only one entry for each file extension didn't help me. My document already had only one entry for each.

So, why might my icons be getting stripped out?

I will also note that the icons (PDF included) seem to be showing up correctly next to items in a regular document library, but they just are not showing up in search results.

Comment: Check the search results master page perhaps?  See what is attempting to be displayed in that src attribute.  might be a clue there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah.  My literal use of the configuration instructions document was the problem.  It suggested adding this line to the docicon.xml file:

```
<Mapping Key="pdf" Value="pdf.gif">
```

This xml fragment doesn't close the tag, so my resulting xml document wasn't valid. Closing the tag like so

```
<Mapping Key="pdf" Value="pdf.gif" />
```

And restarting IIS solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in SharePoint Foundation the pdf icon only shows up in the DocLibrary view... in search results, the old unidentified icon still shows.

Comment: True, but how is that related to this 2010 question about ifilter and search?